# Why is embedded Stackblitz project unable to display preview pane?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, embed, stackblitz

I am trying to embed Stackblitz projects in my Angular application. The embedded project editor pane displays correctly. But the preview pane doesn't display the preview. Instead, it shows an error as follows:

```
Error occurred:
Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/~'
```

The preview pane displayed correctly once or twice but later on none of the embedded links were able to display the preview. Although, the project is working fine in [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-pstdzr?file=index.html)

I am using Chrome Version 100.0.4896.88 on Windows 10. Please help if there is any way to resolve this.
I am getting error related to webcontainer as follows:
[image]

Comment: Do you use any chrome extension? It would help if you tried to test it in the incognito tab.

Comment: It is not working even in incognito mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in stackblitz which caused this error while embedding static html/css/js projects. But the bug was fixed recently by the stackblitz team. It's working fine now. Thanks to the stackblitz team. Happy coding!!